# CaptiveNetwork : CNSetSupportedSSIDs usage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, wifi, captivenetwork

I tried to use CaptiveNetwork in order to replace the web sheet that for user authentication with the network. The method is [CNSetSupportedSSIDs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CNSetSupportedSSIDs).

I have tried to add this method in AppDelegate of my app, but when I want to use a hotspot with the SSID that I have registred with the method above, nothing happend. The web sheet not appear, but my app is not opened.

This is my code :

```
CFStringRef ssids[2] = { CFSTR("Wifi 1"), CFSTR("Wifi 2") };
CFArrayRef arr_ssids = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (const void **)ssids, 2, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);

if( CNSetSupportedSSIDs((CFArrayRef)array))
{
    NSLog(@"Successfully registered supported network SSIDs");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error: Failed to register supported network SSIDs");
}
CFRelease(arr_ssids);
```

PS : I have also added an URL scheme to my app.

Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have submitted a bug to apple and they answer that it will not pop up our app.

Comment: What does it do in such a case?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is not a complete implementation by Apple. You need to have valid 'entitlements' to use their system library. See this handy post explaining it some more:

http://kalapun.com/blog/2013/02/11/reverse-engineering-ios-app/

Answer (score -2):

In any way, this code contains a type-o. CNSetSupportedSsids should be fitted with arr_ssids in your code snippet here. I don't know what kind of variable 'array' is, but it probably doesn't contain the dat you'd desire.

Comment: This does not answer the question.